# The if expression evaluated to False but it is executed anyway

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, boolean

```
for i in range(6, 21):
for y in range(len(lst)):
    if i % lst[y] != 0 and i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and i != lst[-1]:
        lst.append(i)
        print(lst)
```

The output is:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 7, 11]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 7, 11, 13]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 7, 11, 13, 17]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19,    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

so, for the second seven: 7 % 3 != 0(TRUE) and i % 2,3,5 != 0(TRUE) and i != lst[-1](7 != 7 -> FALSE), why the list appends the second seven?

Comment: What is the initial content of the `lst` list?

Comment: Sorry, the initial content of the lst is -> lst = [2, 3, 5]

Comment: I get `[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]` finally.

Comment: Yeah, the level of indentation of the print method was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code, with a fixed indent and an initial value of `lst`:

```
lst=[2,3,5]
for i in range(6, 21):
    for y in range(len(lst)):
        if i % lst[y] != 0 and i % 2 != 0 and i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0 and i != lst[-1]:
            lst.append(i)
            print(lst)
```

Gives me that:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Are you sure you are posting in your question the same code?

Comment: Yes, but in the shell(I don't know why) my output is in the first post. But if I open a new file and copy paste the code, I see the same output as you.

Comment: You probably forgot to reinit `lst` to its initial value or do a mistake in the indent. I'm not able to reproduce your output, even in the shell.

Comment: Thanks for your respone. I have another question: with the condition i % lst[y] != 0 in the if expression, why the number 121 is added to the list, because 121 % 11 != 0(FALSE).

Comment: 121 is added when y equals 0. In that case you have: `121 % 2 != 0 and 121 % 2 != 0 and 121 % 3 != 0 and 121 % 5 != 0 and 121 % 119 != 0`.